# Can't set text to text view

Tags: java, android

My application crashes when I set a text to textView which is located in `nav_header_main`

My application crashes when i set a text to text view which is located in `nav_header_main` can't set text to `textView`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
             logoutStudent();
        }
        // Fetching Student details from SQLite
        HashMap<String, String> student = db.getStudentDetails();

        String name = student.get("name");
       // String section = student.get("section");
        TextView  s_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.student_name);

        s_name.setText("please work!");
```

here is the layout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/student_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:textColor="@color/bg_register" />
I expect the output to set the text, but the app is crashing.
```

Comment: What is the exception you get? Is it a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: the app is crashing

Comment: and the log is" Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable"

Comment: obviously null pointer exception it is java and android... the log is" Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable" and "thread exiting with uncaught exception"

Comment: If you include the full stacktrace from Logcat that would help clear things up. But it sounds like your problem is not in setting the text to the TextView, but somewhere else entirely since you are mentioned a log related to "RippleDrawable"

Comment: try cleaning your project. your crash has nothing to do with the textview.

Comment: I did clean my project. there is no such thing "RippleDrawable" in my entire project except in the log.  I am lost . I cant set a text to TextView from MainActivity to nav_header_main

Comment: post your log @yomefisseha

Answer (score 0):

```
NavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View headerView = navView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView hname= headerView.findViewById(R.id.headername);
 hname.setText("Your Navigation Text here!");
```